# Other cluster forks not able to get requests when one of the forks is stuck in a blocking operation

Tags: node.js

I have a simple http server but it does some blocking operation before serving a request. So I thought forking a few child processes should take care of serving more requests if one of them is stuck in a blocking process.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.on('exit', cluster.fork);
    cluster.fork(); cluster.fork(); cluster.fork(); 
    return;
}

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('req get');
    var i = 0;
    while (i++ < 100000000) setTimeout(); // blocking operation
    res.end('Hello World\n');
    console.log('req served');
}).listen(80);
console.log('Server listening on port 80');
```

It starts 3 forks. But it's always stuck at just handling 1 request. If I open 2 or more tabs pointing to the address simultaneously I should at least be able to see `req get` in the console those many times instantaneously, right? But I only see it just 1 time. All other requests fail to be recieved by the other forks that are presumably idle.

```
Server listening on port 80
Server listening on port 80
Server listening on port 80
req get
```

Only when one of them dies do I see another fork picking up the pending request

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
req get
Server listening on port 80
```

What's stopping my other forks to listen to new requests when one of the fork is stuck in a blocking operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not in node.  Try making the parallel requests with `curl`, or a similar tool.  You will see that, as expected, each process handles one request at a time for a total of 3 concurrent requests.

The issue here is your browser.  From testing, it appears that browsers are reluctant to make more than one concurrent request at a time to the same domain.

However, I can't find documentation to this effect - it appears that most browsers are intended to make at least 2, and sometimes many more, concurrent requests per domain.  This might be a special-case on localhost - I see different behavior when I proxy my local server out to a remote machine and request it through the remote domain.